# How can I create a new line after a set of characters in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the following code:

```
text = input('Enter your text: ')
if len(text) >= 16:
    text = text.replace(' ', '\n')
    print(f'Your new text is:\n{text}')
```

If a user inputs `blah blah blah blah` the user would get the following output:

```
Your new text is:
blah
blah
blah
blah
```

I'm just wondering how can I make my code add a new line after the last available space before the 16 characters mark. So the output should end up being:

```
Your new text is:
blah blah blah
blah
```

I'm fairly new to python and I feel like I'm missing some sort of method that can get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text = input('Enter your text: ')
list_ = text.split(' ')

if len(text) >= 16:
   for i, j in zip(range(len(list_)),list_):
      if i == len(list_)-1:
         break
      print(j, end=' ')
   print('\n'+ j)
```

Comment: This does work in this case but if the user inputs something like ```blahh blahh blahh blahh``` it won't turn out looking good. It has to replace an empty space

Comment: Now @Quessts check out my logic now

Comment: Please mention properly for your input type in future

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your original problem is happening is because `text = text.replace(' ', '\n')` will replace **all** of the spaces with a newline character.

Also, the current answers will not work if the user inputs a string that is **very** long - the 2nd `print()` could result in a line that is longer than 16 characters. For example:

```
>>> text = "blah " * 20
>>> print(text[:15])
blah blah blah 
>>> print(text[15:])
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
```

For this to work on arbitrarily long user inputs, I'd suggest using a loop:

```
>>> text = "blah " * 20
>>> while len(text) > 16:
...     index = text[:16].rindex(' ') # finds the last space in the first 16 chars
...     print(text[:index].strip()) # strip() removes trailing spaces
...     text = text[index:] # Updates text to remove what we just printed
... 
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah blah

>>> print(text.strip()) # Prints any remaining text after the loop
blah blah
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`rindex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rindex#str.rindex) to search for the last occurrence of a space and then memorise the index position. As strings in Python are [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) I'd just form a new one with a `\n` in the middle, like this:

```
text = input('Enter your text: ')
if len(text) >= 16:
     last_space_before_16 = text[:16].rindex(' ')
     text = text[:last_space_before_16] + '\n' + text[last_space_before_16+1:]
     print(f'Your new text is:\n{text}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a regex based approach here:

```py
inp = "blah blah blah blah"
output = re.sub(r'^(.{1,16})\s+', r'\1\n', inp)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
blah blah blah
blah
```

The strategy here is to greedily match up to 16 characters, which are followed by breaking whitespace characters.  Then, we replace by adding a newline character.

Answer (score 0):

```
import textwrap

text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vehicula lorem vitae quam commodo, at interdum lectus maximus."

wrapped_text = textwrap.fill(text, width=16)

print(wrapped_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar task, used textwrap built-in to wrap the text. You can also use a TextWrapper object when dealing with more than one or two text strings.

```
from textwrap import fill

text = "blah " * 20
print(fill(text, 16))

# Output
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah
```

Answer (score -1):

You can limit it to the first 16 characters by using this code:

```
text = text[:15]
print(text)
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. It's not _just_ about printing the 1st 16, but how to print the first 16 _and then_ the next set of characters in a separate line ("*how can I make my code add a new line after the last available space before the 16 characters mark*")

Comment: Also `text[:15]` is the first example given in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66721634/2227743). Please do not repost existing information.